# need to query XML for value in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a table called parts with an XMLType column called RunList_XML

The XML has several Unit tags example  `<Item> <Unit>420</Unit> </Item> <Item> <Unit>10</Unit> </Item> <Item> <Unit>0</Unit> </Item>`
I want to query to get back a list of all parts 
that have a Unit of 420
I cant seem to figure out how to get this using = 420 or = '420'

the below gives back false positives

```
select * from Parts P
   WHERE P.RunList_XML.extract('ArrayOfItem// /Unit/text()').getStringVal() like  '%420'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `existsnode`:

```
select * from Parts P
   WHERE existsnode(RunList_XML, 'ArrayOfItem//Item[Unit="420"]') = 1
```

`existsnode` returns 1 if node is found and 0 if not.